# Spring .NET oracle connection failed

Tags: .net, spring.net

In the Spring .NET, I need to connect to Oracle database, I am sure the connection info is correct, but still not open Oracle connection.

The provider is using 'OracleODP-2.0', how can I verify I have correct Oracle .NET driver installed in my project / pc ?

The exception is

```
[OracleException (0x80004005)]
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck) +1440
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src) +80
   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open() +7561
```

Thanks

Comment: "I am sure the connection info is correct" - apparently Oracle and .NET disagree with you.  Believe the fact that you don't have a connection and figure out what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem.  It doesn't have anything to do with the connection string, and we'll assume that it is correct.  What I found is that critical files from the Oracle client were missing.  Once I added them, then I stopped getting this error.  I have narrowed it down to the following minimum number of files.  More files may be required for advanced functionality, but these are the minimum you should have in your installation.  I am using the *OracleClient  11.2.0.3.0*:

- **Oracle.DataAccess.dll**  *(Main reference assembly)*
- **OraOps11w.dll**
- **oci.dll**
- **oraociei11.dll** *(Ths was the main DLL that fixed the Open() exception error)*